# Is it possible to upload these files to a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In my file upload script, I currently have all the files going to an /upload directory. Is it possible for me to upload it to a database as well as the upload directory so it is easier for me to manage?

```
<?php

require 'header.php';

?>

<center>
<?php

$uniqueid = uniqid();
$file = $uniqueid. basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$target_dir = "uploads/$uniqueid";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        //echo "File is not an image.";
      //  $uploadOk = 1;
    }
}
?>
<br>
<?php
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo " Sorry, the file already exists or";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
?>
<br>
<?php
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "txt") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF and TXT files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "your file was not uploaded correctly. Please try again or contact support!.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "Your file has been uploaded
        <br><br><br><br>
         <img src='uploads/$file'>";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
</center>
```

Comment: *"Is it possible to upload these files to a MySQL database?"* - have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: You can, but it may turn out to be more difficult to manage two instances of a file, Unless you mean to just add the filenames and locations to a database?

Comment: How would you suggest I go about doing it?

Comment: You should upload the files off the document root, like `/var/uploads/***` (so people can't access it directly). Then have PHP `readfile` the uploads once authentication has been established. You can save the links to your database too.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **yes**, it's possible.

Real answer: **you probably shouldn't**.  Serving files from MySQL is 5-10x slower than serving static files from the filesystem with most web servers (like Apache, Nginx, etc).

Comment: How would you suggest I go about doing it?

Comment: Store the uploaded file in your file system, and save the path/filename in your database.